# jQuery multiple classes lost on append

Tags: jquery, css, dom

Something weird seems to be happening for me in jQuery.

I make a string containing something like the following :

```
myBlock = """<div class="alert alert-success">...</div>"""
```

When I try to use jQuery append

```
$("#msg_container").append(myBlock)
```

What I get is a div in the DOM like this

```
<div alert-success="" class="alert">blah</div>
```

How can I append something with two classes using jQuery?

Comment: Why not save the classes to a variable, append the div, and then re-add the classes?

Comment: @chockleyc Well, if I have to, I may have to. But I'd rather not. In truth these blocks are assembled in a commonly used routine, which is called and the results appended all over the place. If I can keep everything encapsulated in that routine, it's a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure why you have so many quotes on the beginning, but this will do:

```
myBlock = "<div class='alert alert-success'>...</div>"
```

You need single quotes for the class values inside a double quoted string.

Comment: I have so many quotes because I'm writing in CoffeeScript :-)

Comment: @interstar -- Ohhhh, gotcha. Not too familiar with the syntax, so at first glance I was little lost. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
myBlock = '<div class="alert alert-success">...</div>'

or 

myBlock = "<div class='alert alert-success'>...</div>"
```

Comment: No, the triple quote is a CoffeeScript thing.